# Solving for mutual inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I had some confusion regarding notation when searching online for formulas for determining mutual inductance of two solenoids and would like to double check I'm interpreting it correctly.

Here is the formula I'm using as a definition for Mutual Inductance.

$$ -N_2 * \frac{\partial{\Phi_{21}}}{\partial{t}} = M_{21} * \frac{\partial{i_1}}{\partial{t}} $$

$ M_{21} = M_{12} = M $ is the mutual inductance.

$ \frac{\partial{\Phi_{21}}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial{(B_1*A_2)}}{\partial{t}}$ is the change in flux through $A_2$ due to Magnetic Field $B_1$.  I'm a little unsure whether I've interpreted this correctly, and I hope I don't have it reversed.

These are my steps for solving.

$ B_1 = \mu * n_1 * I_1$

$$ M_{21} = \frac{-N_2*A_2*\frac{\partial{B_1}}{\partial{t}}}{\frac{\partial{I_1}}{\partial{t}}} = - n_2*l_2*A_2*\mu*n_1$$

I have arrived at this derivation using the following assumptions.

$A_2$ is encapsulated entirely within $A_1$.

$A_2 \leq A_1 $

The Magnetic Field $B_1$ is spacially constant within Solenoid 1 (and therefor constant within Solenoid 2 as well).

I also have one more question.

If a change in current in Solenoid A creates a change in flux through Solenoid B, Solenoid B will experience a change in current as a result. Due to the change in Solenoid B's current, this would induce a change in flux through Solenoid A. This cycle seems like it would repeat itself continuously.

Is this actually happening? Do we ignore its effects as higher order terms that are negligible compared to the initial change in flux? Does the mutual inductance equation I started with somehow capture the

$\Delta{A_1} => \Delta{B_1}$

$\Delta{B_1} => \Delta{A_2}$

$\Delta{A_2} => \Delta{B_2}$

$...$

Comment: *"This cycle seems like it would repeat itself continuously."* - it's not so much a cycle as you've described.  In practice, whatever 'drives' the change in current A 'feels' some effect of the load on solenoid B more or less instantaneously.  That is, it's not that a change in current A 'initiates' a change in current B (which then 'initiates' change in current B etc. etc.), the change in current A in and current B are, *at all times* (at the typical operating frequencies), related via the coupled equations.  If this isn't what you're getting at, then please clarify your question.